# How do I get Rid of this error main.cpp:43:19: error: no viable overloaded '=' novowels[100] = remove(name[100]);

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, overloaded-strings

## Your program must contain a function to remove all

the vowels and a function to determine whether a
character is a vowel. I keep recieveing this error

```
main.cpp:43:19: error: no viable overloaded '='     novowels[100] = remove(name[100]); * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
```

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void remove(string name);
bool check(string letter);

int main()

{
   string novowels[100];
   string name[100];
   cout << "Please insert a string: ";
   getline(cin, name[100]);
   novowels[100] = remove(name[100]);  //ERROR IS HERE!!!
   cout << "\n This is your string without vowels homie:\n " << novowels;

   return 0;
}

string remove(string name[100]) {
   int j = 0;
   bool trueorfalse;
   string novowels[100];
   for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
      trueorfalse = check(name[i]);
      if (trueorfalse == false) {
         novowels[j] = name[i];
         j++;
      } else if (trueorfalse == true) {

      } else {
         break;
      }

   }
   return novowels[100];
}

bool check(string letter) {

   if (letter == "a" || letter == "e" || letter == "i" || letter == "o" ||     letter == "u" || letter == "A" || letter == "E" || letter == "I" || letter == "O" || letter == "U") {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Trying to access the 101st element of an array with 100 elements will not end well. I don't think you meant for those to be arrays at all.

Comment: I think you should replace all of your "string" to "char".

Comment: You have declared two different overloads of `remove`: `void remove(string)` and `string remove(string*)`. You have only defined the latter, but you are calling the former. The version you are actually calling doesn't return any value, and thus cannot appear on the right hand side of an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

= operator can't assign a void value to integer or string or ...

because your remove don't return any things you can't use this function at right side of assignment.